# Roulette Wheel Selection in Netlogo using Agent Variables, not Constants

Tags: netlogo, roulette-wheel-selection

I hope this is a simple solution, but I'm having a difficult time with it.

---

**Problem:**

I would like to weight the probability of something occurring by an variable not a constant

**Setup**

1. My agent is a farm.
2. Farms own four variables that represent the
       number of cows, goats, pigs, and sheep on it.
3. When a farm wants to
       remove an animal, I'd like the likelihood to remove a member of a
       particular species to be directly proportional to quantity of each
       species on the farm (i.e. if there are 7 goats, 2 cows, and 1 pig,
       there is a 70% probability of taking a goat and a zero percent
       probability of taking a sheep)

I have found formula like this for when you know the exact numerical weight that each value will have:

```
to-report random-weighted [values weights]        
  let selector (random-float sum weights) 
  let running-sum 0 
    (foreach values weights [ 
      set running-sum (running-sum + ?2)    ; Random-Weighted Created by NickBenn
      if (running-sum > selector) [ 
        report ?1 
      ] 
    ]) 
end
```

and the methods described in the rnd extension. But both of these throw the "expected a constant" error when i put "Cow" in instead of a constant.

Something like:

```
 to example1
  let values ["Cow" "Sheep" "Goat" "Pig"]
  let probabilities [2 0 7 1]
  let indices n-values length values [ ? ]               ; Made by Nicolas Payette
  let index rnd:weighted-one-of indices [ item ? probabilities ]
  let loca item index values
end
```

works well, but if I were to replace it with:

```
to example1
      let values ["Cow" "Sheep" "Goat" "Pig"]
      let probabilities [Num-Cows Num-Sheep Num-Goats Num-Pigs]
      let indices n-values length values [ ? ]               ; Made by Nicolas Payette
      let index rnd:weighted-one-of indices [ item ? probabilities ]
      let loca item index values
    end
```

it fails.

Comment: let probabilities (list Num-Cows Num-Sheep Num-Goats Num-Pigs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alan is right: you need to use the [`list`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#list) primitive (as opposed to just brackets) when you want to construct a list from anything else than constants.

I would add two things to that:

- The latest version of the `rnd` extension has two sets of primitives: [one for agentsets, and one for lists](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension/pull/8). So you should probably update and use the [`rnd:weighted-one-of-list`](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension#rndweighted-one-of-list-list-reporter-task) primitive.
- Your code is based around using indices to pick an item. That's fine, but that's not the only way to do it.

You could also have something like:

```
to example1
  let values ["Cow" "Sheep" "Goat" "Pig"]
  let probabilities (list Num-Cows Num-Sheep Num-Goats Num-Pigs)
  let loca first rnd:weighted-one-of-list (map list values probabilities) last
end
```

This may be a bit trickier to understand, but here is the gist of it:

- The `(map list values probabilities)` expression takes both your `values` list and your `probabilities` list and "zips" them together using the `list` primitive, resulting in a list of pairs: `[["Cow" 2] ["Sheep" 0] ["Goat" 7] ["Pig" 1]]`.
- We pass the [`last`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#last) reporter to the `rnd:weighted-one-of-list` primitive to tell it that the last (i.e., second) item of each of these pairs should be used as the probability.
- Since `rnd:weighted-one-of-list` operates on a list of pairs, the item it returns will be a pair (e.g., `["Goat" 7]`). We are only interested in the first item of the pair, so we extract it with the [`first`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#first) reporter.

Note that we use the NetLogo's concise syntax for tasks when passing `list` as an argument to `map` and `last` as an argument to `rnd:weighted-n-of`. You could replace `list` with `[ (list ?1 ?2) ]` and `last` with `[ last ? ]`, but it would be uglier.